# Can I show the label and make the User not able to interact with a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@Html.DropDownList("Accnt", new SelectList(ViewBag.Accounts, "Value", "Text"), "Account")
```

"Account" appears at the top of the list and the User is able to interact with it as a item. I would like to know if is possible to present the value but make it disable to the user.

[image: Photo Example]

Comment: Five second search in Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=%40Html.DropDownList&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#newwindow=1&q=@Html.DropDownList+disable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Jquery`  for that purpose and find that option with text since it does not have any value

Add this link in the `head` if you do not have jquery in scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and add this script in the `body`

```
<script>

    $(function(){

        $('select[name=Accnt] option').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf('Account') >= 0) $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, you want to disable a particular item of the list.

For that you can use JQuery, like that:

```
$('#Accounts option[value*="Accounts"]').prop('disabled', true);
```